# Почему кнопка доступна только при "LostFocus"?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

Определил условие для доступности кнопки (нажие показано) и вроде бы оно работает, но кнопка становится доступной только тогда, когда нажмёшь мышкой в любой части проги. В приложении есть и другие кнопки, доступность у которых работает исправно. Да, дело плохо не по MVVM писать приложение...

```
 DataGrid str = (DataGrid)App.Current.MainWindow.FindName("TableName");

 public RelayCommand<StudentModel> endGame = null;
 public RelayCommand<StudentModel> EndGame => endGame ?? (endGame = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
  {
     ChangeTextColorToDefault();
     StopTimer();

     str.IsEnabled = false;
     deviceManager.votumManager.Stop();
  },
    (param) =>
   {
     var x = str.Columns[7].GetCellContent(str.Items[0]) as TextBlock;
      return str.IsEnabled && x != null ? x.Text != "" : false;
    }));
```

Класс команды:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : CommandBase
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute.Invoke((T)parameter);
    public override void Execute(object parameter) { _execute.Invoke((T)parameter); }
}
```

Базовый класс команды:

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
   add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
   remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
  }

  public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
  public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Закончить игру" Style="{StaticResource EndGame}"
  FontWeight="Bold" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="15"
  Command="{Binding EndGame}"/>
```

Comment: Почему вы используете и привязки и контролы разом? Если используете привязки, так используйте их везде и всегда.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня здесь нарушение MVVM...)) Но не понял про "и привязки и контролы" разом?

Comment: Нарушение - не то слово, но не о нем сейчас речь. Смотрите, к примеру есть `TextBox `, вы можете сделать `<TextBox x:Name="tb"/>` и в коде использовать `tb.Text = "Привет мир!";`, вроде все хорошо, работает, да? Как бы не так. У вас интерфейс забивается ненужной информацией и вместо того, чтобы отобразить, он еще начинает в себе хранить данные, это не есть хорошо. Также вы теряете гибкость, допустим у вас есть еще и `TextBlock`, как вы ему будете задавать тот же "Привет мир"? Опять запихивать в него ненужные данные?

Comment: Отделите данные от интерфейса, не грузите его лишней информацией, а также думайте про будущее, как вы в будущем будете работать с этим кодом. Пример выше можно было бы сделать так: `public string Text { get; set; } = "Привет мир!";` и в XAML уже `<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>`, все, теперь не надо делать всяких `as TextBlock` или `(DataGrid)App.Current.MainWindow.FindName("TableName")`, ибо у нас в коде есть четко сформированное свойство, к которому мы просто можем обратиться, а интерфейс это подхватит (если есть INPC).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня так и есть. Есть сущность или модель, биндюсь к её св-вам. Если бы был обычный TextBox, сделал бы, как Вы написали, а так у меня DataGrid, в котором есть <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Rating, Mode=OneWay}"/>. Вот, собственно, в команде и надо смотреть, если он null или "", то кнопка отключена, я это делаю, но у кнопки срабатывает изменение её состояния, только при LostFocus.

Comment: `DataGrid str = (DataGrid)App.Current.MainWindow.FindName("TableName");` - это по вашему так и есть? Это называется "Ей, приложение, найди мне элемент с именем `TableName` и дай мне его как DataGrid, общаться с ним буду!". А должно быть "Выделенный рейтинг, ты являешся `NULL`?". У вас должна быть коллекция, которая установлена как `ItemsSource` и свойство того же типа, что и у коллекции, который будет иметь то, что выбрал пользователь и в разметке тогда `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">`, все, пользователь выбрал, вы получи это в `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы всё правильно говорите. За исключением этой строчки и всё, что с ней связано далее по коду, у меня именно так, как Вы описали. Есть ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); , она забиндина к ItemSource у DataGrid. Мне не нужно  получать значение, выделенной ячейки пользователем или того, что будет в SelectedItem. У Item есть св-во Rating, не знал, что придумать, чтобы проверить его на NULL или "" в коде, а так же не знал, как сделать так, чтобы кнопкой отключить DataGrid и включить его, придумал вот это.

Comment: Да как так то?) Уберите вот это `DataGrid str = (DataGrid)App.Current.MainWindow.FindName("TableName");`, вы вообще не должны такое делать! У вас как вы говорите есть `ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }`, так берите из нее тогда нужное значение и проверяйте на null. Забудьте, что у вас вообще есть интерфейс, как бы вы решили эту задачу допустим в консольном проекте?

Comment: Всё, всё. Убираю её!) Ну, а как мне сделать бан ДатаГрида по нажатию кнопки, чтобы пользователь не мог ничего в нём менять?

Comment: Там есть свойство `IsReadOnly`, привязывайте и меняйте.

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе, и актуализируйте сам вопрос, пожалуйста. Я 2 раза перечитал вопрос и комментарии, и ничего не понял. Так же, вы используете `CanExecute` комады, неплохо было бы увидеть реализацию `RelayCommand`. И было бы удобнее ситать вопрос, если бы отступ в коде был бы не на половину экрана мобильного, отыорматируйте пожалуста, если не трудно.

Comment: @aepot сделал, так получше будет

Comment: @Genas а класс `CommandBase` - это что? MVVM Light? Ну в любом случае для перерасчета `CanExecute` команды используется `CommandManager`, и событие `RequerySuggested`, которое вызывается в момент любого события ввода: клик мышкой, кнопка, и так далее. А вам как я понял, надо вызывать Requery до того, как что-то произойдет в интерфейсе. То есть на момент проверки `CanExecute` еще не произошло то что должно влиять на доступность кнопки. Попробуйте вызвать пересчет принудительно из кода `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`. Но я еще подумаю, и может чуть позже напишу пример для MVVM.

Comment: @aepot Нет, это не MVVM Light. Просто базовый класс по Троелсону. Вызвал CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() там, где условие доступности кнопки проверяется и кнопки заработали так как нужно )))

Comment: Еще на данном этапе условие `str.IsEnabled && x != null ? x.Text != "" : false` можно упростить до `str.IsEnabled && x?.Text?.Length > 0`. Попробуйте обновить условие, поменяется что-нибудь или нет.

Comment: @Genas надеюсь вы вызвали `InvalidateRequerySuggested` не в `CanExecute`. Если это так, то вы просто создали бесконечный цикл и нагрузку на процессор. Вызывать Invalidate в CanExecute нельзя. Потому что будет `CanExecute=>Invalidate=>CanExecute=>Invalidate...`

Comment: Вызывать `InvalidateRequerySuggested` можно там, где например вы меняете `IsEnabled` для строки или отслеживаете изменения текста в 7 колонке. То есть там, где меняются аргументы условия для видимости кнопки.

Comment: @aepot Упрощение не помогло. Вы прям, как знаете, всё, что я делаю заранее. Да, именно там и вызвал для проверки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте добавим немного [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) и привязок к вашему решению на основе этого простого примера. Создайте чистое WPF приложение и протестируйте решение.

Я использую 2 вспомогательных класса для `INotifyPropertyChanged` и для `ICommand`, немного отличается от вашего, но я спустя несколько лет программирования не увидел нужды в дополнительном `CommandBase`, если только ради подхода SRP (из SOLID), но тоже сомнительное удовольствие. На ваше усмотрение, брать это, или использовать своё.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Кстати класс команды взят из примера в документации по ссылке в самом начале этого ответа. Но по сути логически он повторяет то что у вас.

Далее, я создал класс данных, к которому буду привязывать `DataGrid`

```csharp
public class MyItem : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myValue;
    private bool _enabled = true;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => _enabled;
        set
        {
            _enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string MyValue
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set
        {
            _myValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Свойство `Enabled` я просто привяжу сюда, и буду управлять активностью строки таблицы через него.

Далее, View Model главного окна, сюда я направлю `DataContext` окна (см. в разметке), чтобы биндинги смогли найти все необходимые свойства для привязки здесь.

Для примера изменения активности кнопки на основе `CanExecute`, при этом не по событию ввода, в просто из кода, запущу параллельную задачу, которая 2 секунды спит, а потом меняет свойство `Enabled` у текущего элемента, который передал через параметр.

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;
    private ICommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is MyItem item)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.MyValue);
            Task.Run(() => 
            { 
                Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                item.Enabled = !item.Enabled;
                // так как вызов CommandManager из стороннего потока не сработает, вызываю через диспетчер
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested());
            });
        }
    }, parameter => parameter is MyItem item && item.Enabled && item.MyValue?.Length > 0));

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get => _myItems;
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>
        {
            new MyItem { MyValue = "Первая строка" },
            new MyItem { MyValue = "Вторая строка" },
            new MyItem { MyValue = "" }
        };
    }
}
```

Разметка

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Focusable="False">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="5" Padding="5,0" Content="Click me!" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding MyItems/}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Строка" Binding="{Binding MyValue}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, она станет отключена спустя 2 секунды автоматически.

Обратите внимание на `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` у таблицы, оно позволяет мне по-хитрому прибиндить параметр команды в кнопке.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, за решение и отличный пример. Кажется, это называется второе поколение. В рамках своего решения на .Net Core WPF и буду делать это приложение с использованием полноценного MVVM. Хитрость IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" в том, что SelectedItem общий для тех элементов, у которых мы ставим общий ресурс. В данном примере - это коллекция. Правильно?

Comment: Как понимать сеттер этого св-ва? public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get => _myItems;
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

Comment: @Genas `OnPropertyChanged()` здесь - сообщить биндингу что свойство поменялось и чтобы он сообщил контролу, а контрол обновил интерфейс. Вы меняете свойство, интерфейс меняется сам и наоборот. Так и работают привязки.

Comment: @Genas Про синхронизаци - да, правильно, что-типа того. Подробнее сможете узнать, если начнете изучать `Binding` и узнаете, что для коллекции он создает прослойку из класса `CollectionView`, там и кроются нюансы работы с коллекциями. В моем примере таблица синхронизирует текущий элемент с этой самой `CollectionView`, а `Binding` в кнопке его подхватывает.

Comment: Интересно и увлекательно. Вот как бы это по щелчку пальца в голову помещать?.. )) Про сеттер имел в виду вот это - {_myItems = value;} Что в value мы будем передавать?

Comment: @Genas `value` в контексте сеттера - ключевое слово, имеющее тот же тип, что и у свойства и значение, которое в это свойство надо записать. Другими словами оно на момент исполнения содержит то значение, что прилетело сеттеру извне. [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).